# Filtering XML via XMLFilter in Excel, but wrong XPath

Tags: excel, xml, xpath, filter

I have an XML from which I want to filter the Title and EMail.

This is the XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<entry xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom" xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices" xmlns:georss="http://www.georss.org/georss" xmlns:gml="http://www.opengis.net/gml" xmlns:m="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/metadata" xml:base="https://mysite/vis/_api/">
   <id>https://mysite/vis/_api/Web/GetUserById(1284)</id>
   <category term="SP.User" scheme="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/scheme" />
   <link rel="edit" href="Web/GetUserById(1284)" />
   <link rel="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/related/Groups" type="application/atom+xml;type=feed" title="Groups" href="Web/GetUserById(1284)/Groups" />
   <title />
   <updated>2020-01-15T18:23:48Z</updated>
   <author>
      <name />
   </author>
   <content type="application/xml">
      <m:properties>
         <d:Id m:type="Edm.Int32">1284</d:Id>
         <d:IsHiddenInUI m:type="Edm.Boolean">false</d:IsHiddenInUI>
         <d:LoginName>i:0#.w|opmain\xespsa</d:LoginName>
         <d:Title>Alex, Johnson</d:Title>
         <d:PrincipalType m:type="Edm.Int32">1</d:PrincipalType>
         <d:Email>Alex.Johnson@stackoverflow.net</d:Email>
         <d:IsSiteAdmin m:type="Edm.Boolean">false</d:IsSiteAdmin>
         <d:UserId m:type="SP.UserIdInfo">
            <d:NameId>s-1-5-21-1377870913-3677095212-3270174719-20443</d:NameId>
            <d:NameIdIssuer>urn:office:idp:activedirectory</d:NameIdIssuer>
         </d:UserId>
      </m:properties>
   </content>
</entry>
```

I tried using the XMLFILTER function from Excel, but my XPath is wrong:

```
=XMLFILTERN(E4;"//content/title[1]")
```

How can I get the correct xpath in this case since Title is inside content?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**TLDR/*from comments***: Excel doesn't care about namespaces. Reuse the prefixes in the source XML and ignore the default namespace...

```
//content/m:properties/d:Title
```

---

It's probably because your XML has namespaces.

`content` is in the default namespace `http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom`.

`properties` is in the namespace `http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/metadata` bound to the prefix `m`.

`Title` is in the namespace `http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices` bound to the prefix `d`.

I'm not sure how Excel/XMLFILTER handles namespaces in XPath (hopefully someone answers that does), but ideally you'd bind those namespace uris to prefixes and use the prefixes in the XPath.

If you can't, you'll probably have to resort to using [local-name()](https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-10/#function-local-name)...

```
//*[local-name()='content']/*[local-name()='properties']/*[local-name()='Title']
```

If there's a possibility of elements with the same local name, but different namespaces (and you need to distinguish between them), you can also use `namespace-uri()`...

```
//*[local-name()='content' and namespace-uri()='http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom']/*[local-name()='properties' and namespace-uri()='http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/metadata']/*[local-name()='Title' and namespace-uri()='http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices']
```

Of course this is all assuming that those two XPath 1.0 functions are supported.

Comment: Thanks, but I get a formatting error when trying to use the XMLFilter function while using the XPath you provided. Can you reproduce it on your Excel?

Comment: @PoliticsStudent - Unfortunately I can only answer from a pure XPath perspective since I've never used XMLFILTER. Maybe try `//default:content/m:properties/d:Title` or `//content/m:properties/d:Title`. It's possible that XMLFILTER is just looking for the same namespace prefixes.

Comment: @PoliticsStudent - a miracle! Which one worked? I’ll update my answer for future visitors.

Answer (score 1):

For the xPath argument in Excel, you should use the namespace:

The full path:

```
//content/m:properties/d:Title
//content/m:properties/d:Email
```

In your particular instance, you can more simply use:

```
//d:Title
//d:Email
```